# Не могу завершить исполнение кода в express.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

1 вопрос:
Если приложение крашится, оно крашится только у оного пользователя(у которого произошла ошибка) или для всех?

2 вопрос:
На сайте есть форма, аяксом отправляется пост запрос к серверу, где он обрабатывается. Однако форму можно отправить пустую (если захотеть) и тогда приложение крашится. Чтобы этого избежать, нужно проверить переменную на 'undefined' и вернуть ошибку. Однако выяснилось, что я, почему-то, не могу с помощью res.end() завершить исполнение кода, ошибка всё равно вылетает, будто переменные инициализируются перед какими-либо действиями.

```js
app.post('/record', function(req, res, next) {

res.send('error'); res.end(); //Всё равно вылетает ошибка из кода ниже, так как res.body.id из пост запроса == Indifined
  
pool.query("INSERT INTO `record` (id) VALUES ("+pool.escape(req.body.id), function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {console.log(err); res.send('error');}
            ratePlease(0, 0);
          });
  })
```

```
ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: 'undefined' for column 'novel_id' at row 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для всех.
2. **res.send('error'); res.end();** заменить на **return res.send('error');**